# Spinner Value to String

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

Been making my first app and slow progress is being made. Just wondering how I return a Spinner value to pass it as a string.

Here is my code:

First the event class:

```
public void event(){
    calanderBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.eventBtn);
    calanderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Home");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,  "Cleaning : ");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Second the Spinner Class:

```
public void selectcleaning() {
        spCleaning = (Spinner) findViewById(spinner);

        adapterCleaningType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cleaningType);
        adapterCleaningType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spCleaning.setAdapter(adapterCleaningType);
    }
```

I'm trying to select the value from selectcleaning (Value is either Yes or No) and pass it in the descrption in the Calendar of the event class and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code to get the value

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

or get the value when spinner selected using OnItemSelectedListener ([Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html))

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements 

OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
         Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
         spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the Overrides for the spinner class as so:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here

}});
```

For your purposes 'int position' would equal 0 (yes) or 1 (no)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an on item selected listener. When an item is selected, you can store that value in a global variable. It gets the first item by default too.

```
    spCleaning.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // Value is current spinner item
            globalStringVariable = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        }

        // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            // This is default, before you've selected anything. 
            // It gets the first value.
            globalStringVariable = parent.getItemAtPositon(0);
        }

    });
```